# Entity Framework - Exception Adding an existing object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

When I enter an entity to the db using add() i get the following SqlException (Object already exists)

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '....'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'PROJ.DesignProjects'. 
The duplicate key value is ... The statement has been terminated."} 
System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

I then fix it to run a remove before adding and I get

```
{"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."}
```

How can I upsert then?

Comment: How is your `Id` generated? by the database? are you using `DbContext`?

Comment: The object is created using new ..() and a simple constructor. The id is than set to the same id as in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AddOrUpdate() method:

```
yourContext.yourDbSet.AddOrUpdate(yourObject);
```

**Edit:** further reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx